# Динамическое выделение памяти под строку

Tags: c

Всем привет!
Друзья, помогите, нигде не могу найти толковы ответ на казалось бы простой вопрос.
Пишу код на языке Си (не С++ !). Требуется решить задачу:

"Во всех заданиях предусмотреть захват и освобождение динамической памяти (операции new, delete), решение оформить в виде отдельной функции, которой передается исходная строка. На печать вывести исходную и преобразованную строки.
В строке символов поменять местами символы на четных и нечетных позициях."

В частности очень интересует ответ на вопрос: как осуществить динамическое выделение памяти при помощи new под строку, причём строка вводится с клавиатуры?

Comment: new и delete(delete[]) только в C++, а в Си функции *alloc и free

Comment: думаю, что new/delete - это имена функций, которые нужно написать. Для ввода строки обычно выделяют достаточно большой буфер (на килобайт-два) и этого часто хватает. В противном случае, вводят посимвольно (или небольшими кусками) и с помощью realloc увеличивают буфер.

Comment: @KoVadim В задании же чётко сказано, что это **операции new, delete**, а не функции. Вероятно, задача предполагает использование С++, а не Си.

Comment: @zed но автор при этом использует тег [tag:c] и явно указывает в тексте "на языке C (не С++ !)"

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1530754.html#post8073917

Answer (score 1):

Если верно предположение KoVadim по поводу того, что функции `new` и `delete` вам надо написать, то можно так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>

const unsigned int MAX_LENGTH = 1 * 1024 * 1024;  // Не выделять больше мегабайта памяти
const unsigned int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;             // Выделять блоками по килобайту

char* new() {
    unsigned int str_len = CHUNK_SIZE;
    char *str_ptr = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);           // Выделяем первый килобайтный блок

    if (str_ptr == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Не удалось выделить память!\n");

    int c;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0, c = EOF; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; i++) {
        str_ptr[i] = c;

        if (i == MAX_LENGTH) {
            free(str_ptr);
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Слишком много входных данных!\n");
        }

        if (i == str_len) {                       // Блок заполнен
            str_len = i + CHUNK_SIZE;
            str_ptr = realloc(str_ptr, str_len);  // Расширяем блок на ещё один килобайт
        }
    }
    str_ptr[i] = '\0';                            // Признак конца строки

    return str_ptr;
}

void delete(char* ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}

void swap_chars(char* s) {
    char c;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s) - 1; i += 2) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[i+1];
        s[i + 1] = c;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* buf = new();
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    swap_chars(buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    delete(buf);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

А если программа компилируется под систему совместимую со стандартом POSIX 2013, то функция `new` становится сильно проще

```
char* new() {
    char* buf;
    scanf("%ms", &buf);
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Только не `char c;`, **а `int c;`** (это важно)

Comment: @avp исправил. А почему это важно? И стоит ли добавить приведение типа при присваивании `c` элементу массива?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev: Потому что, во-первых, `getchar` возвращает значения из диапазона `unsigned char`. Такие значения могут не поместиться в диапазон `char`. Во-вторых, `getchar` может вернуть `EOF`. А `EOF` не гарантированно попадает в диапазон представимых значений `char`. Именно поэтому возвращаемое значение `getchar` имеет тип `int`.

Comment: @AnT спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: Также, вы потратили усилия на обработку ошибок, в частности невозможность выделения памяти. Но при этом возможные ошибки при `realloc` почему-то проигнорировали.

Comment: @AnT ваша правда. Как думаете, что лучше сделать в случае ошибки - завершить программу или вернуть буфер такого размера, какой получилось выделить?

Comment: Наверное при нехватке памяти лучше вернуть NULL (так же, как и при конце файла или IO error). Конкретную ошибку можно будет диагностировать, посмотрев `errno` или `ferror/foef`