# Выделение динамической памяти для текста неизвестного размера

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Пытаясь реализовать программу, принимающую на вход текст неизвестного размера написал следующую программу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
    char ch;
    int sentence = 0;
    int symb = 0;
    int slen = 50;
    char** text = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    while (ch != '\n'){
        text[sentence] = (char*)malloc(slen * sizeof(char));
        while (ch != '.'){
            ch = getchar();
            if (symb >= slen){
                slen += 50;
                text[sentence] = (char*)realloc(text[sentence], slen * sizeof(char));
            }
            text[sentence][symb++] = ch;
        }
        text[sentence][symb] = '\0';
        ++sentence;
        text = (char**)realloc(text, (sentence + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        ch = getchar();
        symb = 0;
        slen = 50;  
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= sentence; i++){
        if (text[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s ", text[i]);
    }
}
```

Она работает. Но мне необходимо реализовать считывание программы в отдельной функции. Для этого была написана вторая версия программы, в которой одна из переменных, отвечающих за выделение памяти является не локальной, а передается по ссылке. Но теперь вылетает seg fault, а отладчик ругается на printf. Если же убрать printf  из функции main, ошибка не вылетает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void text_input(char **text, int *sentence);

void main(){
  char** text = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
  int sentence = 0;
  text_input(text, &sentence);


 for (int i = 0; i <= sentence; i++){
                if (text[i] != NULL){
                        printf("%s ", text[i]);
                }
        }
}






void text_input(char **text, int *sentence){
  int slen = 50;
  char ch;
  int symb = 0;

  while (ch != '\n'){
                text[*sentence] = (char*)malloc(slen * sizeof(char));
                while (ch != '.'){
                        ch = getchar();
                        if (symb >= slen - 1){
                                slen += 50;
                                text[*sentence] = 
(char*)realloc(text[*sentence], slen * sizeof(char));
                        }
                        text[*sentence][symb++] = ch;
                }
                text[*sentence][symb] = '\0';
                *sentence += 1;
                text = (char**)realloc(text, (*sentence + 1) * sizeof(char*));
                ch = getchar();
                symb = 0;
                slen = 50;


        }
}
```

Пример ввода текста программы:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: Измените `void text_input (...)` на `char **text_input(...)`, добавьте в ее конец `return text;`, а в `main` вызывайте ее `text = text_input(text, &sentence);`

Comment: Вы задаете какой-то вопрос или просто рассказываете историю создания своей программы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамическое выделение памяти под строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/905103/204271)